# Problem changing the parent group for a node

Tags: nodes, organic-groups

I am trying to programmatically update the parent group of a bunch of nodes. But I am not having much luck. Below is what I have tried. What am I doing wrong here?

```
foreach ($groups AS $group)
{
  $node = node_load($group->nid);
  $node->og_parent = 23; //I also tried "$node->og_parent = array('nid' => 23);"
  node_save($node);
  unset($node);
}
```

One thing to note is that all of these groups already have a parent group set. Also this is on Drupal 6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. Here is what I had to do.

I had to address this slightly differently. I just had to change `$node->og_parent = 23;` to `$node->og_parent->nid = 23;`.

I just had to address the specific node id and that fixed it.